# handling errors from unix commands when called from Popen

Tags: python, multithreading, unix

I have the following method I'm using to test the `bc` unix command ... it takes an expression, executes it and takes the output back ...

```
def run_test(expr=""):

        try:
            process = sp.Popen('bc',
                               stdin=sp.PIPE,
                               stdout=sp.PIPE,
                               stderr=sp.PIPE)
            process.stdin.write(expr)
            result = process.stdout.readline()
            process.stdin.close()
            retval = process.wait()
            return result
        except Exception, e:
            print e


# correct expression, returns '4'
print run_test('2+2\n')
```

However, when I pass a wrong expression `expr`, I would like to handle the error correctly, so I could assert the test case for that `expr` fails properly ...

```
#never stops
print run_test('2 / 0\n')
```

However, the above expression never returns ... I would like to return a value, false for example, that would tell me that expression was invalid, and then when I assert,

```
assertTrue(run_test('2 / 0\n'), False)
```

would work correctly ... How could I achieve it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is happening is that stderr is not being redirected properly.  As you are doing readline, you need to redirect stderr to stdout, via the following command from the python prompt.  You'll need to move it to your function.

```
   def run_test(expr=""):

        try:
            process = sp.Popen('bc',
                               stdin=sp.PIPE,
                               stdout=sp.PIPE,
                               stderr=sp.STDOUT)
            process.stdin.write(expr)
            result = process.stdout.readline()
            process.stdin.close()
            retval = process.wait()
            return result
        except Exception, e:
            print e


# correct expression, returns '4'
print run_test('2+2\n') 

print run_test('2 / 0\n') # now this stops too
```

Docs say: http://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html
Special value that can be used as the stderr argument to Popen and indicates that standard error should go into the same handle as standard output.

Answer (score 0):

1. Your best bet would be to actually do things in python as some
   programs never guarantee to return something sensible.
2. Next best would be to avoid calling programs in interactive mode but
   only in command line mode.
3. After that you could try always appending the exit for the program that you are calling, e.g. for bc use `process.stdin.write(expr + "\nquit\n")`.
4. Last and worst would be to start a timer and if the expression does not terminate before the timer expires kill the process and give a time out error.